# Doing equation in php find tax in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to find the x

```
 $price = 10;
 $tax = x + 20% = 10
 x = $myresult
```

Comment: What is `x`?? and If its variable then you must have an error of not declaring vars

Comment: This is a math question, not a php question.

Comment: Try https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: is that actual code? you need to respond to this, it's important. What you posted doesn't hold water. It would throw an undefined constant and parse error.

Comment: No its not the actual code its an exemple if its possible to find the x

Comment: **then post your real code** - it's literally stitched with errors.

Comment: I've obviously fallen onto deaf ears. Voting to close.

Comment: i have no real code cause i dont know if its possible to do that you dont understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the amount by 20% tax you would multiply by 1.2

To return to the original value before tax was applied you would divide by 1.2

```
$price = $result / 1.2;
```

Comment: I have $price = 10; and i want $result = 8.33333 cause 8.33333 + (8.33333 x 0.2) = 10

Comment: My answer does this. 10 / 1.2 = 8.333333